# ¿ como puedo mandar un json de php a javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Tengo un problema a la hora de llamar una funcion de php desdde javascript y es que en la funcion de php retorno un json pero a la hora de tratar de ver el json me manda 0 como resultado.

esa es la funcion de php que estoy creando para añadir todos los posts a json

```
   function get_aliances_mobile() {
     $colaboracion_terms = $_POST['colaboracion'];
     $paged = 1;
     $posts_per_page = -1;

     $args = array(
       'post_type' => array('empresa'),
       'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
       'paged' => $paged,
       'order' => 'ASC',
       'orderby' => 'date',
      );


     $args['tax_query'] = array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
        addTaxQuery('colaboracion', $colaboracion_terms),
      );

      $ajaxposts = new WP_Query( $args );

      $json_response = $ajaxposts -> get_posts();

      echo $json_response;

      wp_die();
   }

   //add_action('wp_ajax_get_aliances_mobile', 'get_aliances_mobile');
   //add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_aliances_mobile', 'get_aliances_mobile');
```

y este es el codigo que utilizo en javascript:

```
function getAllColaboratorsMobile() {
    form = new FormData();
    form.append("action", "get_aliances_mobile");
    getAlliances(form);
}

function getAlliances(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: data,
        cache:false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("ERROR", errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

ahora lo que me retorna es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El la llamada solo a php, sin usar js te devuelve algo? Si los datos ya vienen en formato json para que usas de nuevo la función `json_encode`?

Comment: en la llamada php me devuelve un array con varios json, osea que si funciona en php pero a la hora de llamarlo en javascript me da 0, igual intente con POSTMAN para ver que traia e igual manda 0

Comment: tienes razon con respecto a lo de json_encode, ya lo cambie para que me mande solo el `$json_response = $ajaxposts -> get_posts();` pero me sigue saliendo 0 en javascript

Comment: Puede que sea la misma función la que esté devolviendo cero. Depura poniendo `var_dump($json_response);` antes del return para verificarlo.

Comment: al añadir el `var_dump($json_response);` me muestra el array con todos los objetos

Comment: Como dice @a-cedano tienes que depurar el código, el js está bien y hace lo que pides que haga. Tienes otro problema en otro sitió y con lo que has facilitado no soy capaz de saber que puede ser

Comment: Y, otra cosa, ¿qué es `MLHttpRequest`?

Comment: me dio el error `ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, y el MLHttpRequest fue un error mio, era XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @ICIM es que en realidad ese es todo el codigo que tengo, en la funcion de php lo que hago es acceder a los posts y en el javascript lo que intento es visualizar esos datos

Comment: si, lo quite del php

Comment: ahora lo agregue pero me sigue dando el error antes mencionado

Comment: perdon, fue un error mio con respecto al get_aliances, en mi php si lo tengo en get_aliances_mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu PHP te falta indicar que envias un documento json.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudo a encontrar la solucion